# Catch Block Not Printing Statement of Invalid Input

Tags: java, validation, types, try-catch

I would like for the user to input a number between 0-9. If they enter a number outside of this range (either a negative or a number greater than 9) they have entered an invalid input. Additionally, I would like to use a try catch block to identify an incorrect input type (string), and also print invalid.

There is no need for the user to re-enter input. Once is fine.

What I have tried so far:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class guessinggame
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("My number is " + randomNumber + ". ");

        System.out.println("I’m thinking of a number between 0 and 9.");
        System.out.println("What is your guess:");


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess = keyboard.nextInt();

            try{
                input = keyboard.nextInt();

            }catch (InputMismatchException e){
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Invalid.");
            }



           if (guess < randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("your guess was too low.");
           }else if (guess > randomNumber){
                System.out.println("your guess was too high.");
            }else if (guess == randomNumber){
                System.out.println("your guess was correct.");
            }else if (guess < 0){
                System.out.println("Invalid.");
            }else if (guess > 9){
                System.out.println("Invalid.");
          }
        }
    }
```

Here is only my try catch block:

```
            try{
                input = keyboard.nextInt();

            }catch (InputMismatchException e){
                guess = keyboard.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Invalid.");
            }
```

The problem I have is, when compiled, and I enter a string input such as "abc", the program creates a run time error of this format:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at guessinggame.main(guessinggame.java:17)
```

When instead all that *should* be displayed after entry of a string is:
`Invalid.` as per the statement `System.out.println("Invalid.");` in my catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is being thrown on this line: `int guess = keyboard.nextInt();`, which is not surrounded by a `try/catch` statement. Just so you know, each time you call `Scanner.nextInt()`, you are asking for a new line. Try doing this:

```
int guess = -1; // This will be an invalid input
try{
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
}catch (InputMismatchException e){
    // Because guess is already -1, "invalid" will be printed out by 
    // Below if statements
}
```

This way, if the user enter an invalid guess, you use your already created if statements to handle it.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was insightful and helped my understanding of the subject of the try/catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no need for the user to re-enter input. Once is fine.

You're asking for input *three times*:

```
int guess = keyboard.nextInt(); // here

try{
    input = keyboard.nextInt(); // here

}catch (InputMismatchException e){
    guess = keyboard.nextInt(); // and here
    System.out.println("Invalid.");
}
```

The first one is throwing the exception.  And since that exception isn't caught, it's terminating the application.

It seems like you just want this:

```
int guess;
try {
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid.");
    return;
}
```

In lieu of the `return` at the end of the `catch` block you might do something else, whatever you want to do is up to you.  But the rest of the logic in the method wouldn't really be applicable if `guess` was never set to a valid `int`, so by default I'm simply exiting the method here.

But basically, if you want the user to enter the input once then only ask for it once.  And any time you want to handle exceptions, wrap the code throwing the exception in a `try/catch` to handle it.